# How many Zombies can a Corpse Flower have?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, undead

On page 127 of Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes, in the stat block for the Corpse Flower, it states:

> The Corpse Flower animates one dead humanoid in its body, turning it into a zombie. The zombie appears in an unoccupied space within 5 feet of the corpse flower and acts immediately after it in the initiative order. The zombie acts as an ally of the corpse flower but isn't under its control, and the flower stench clings to it.

So theoretically, If a Corpse Flower had a constant supply of dead and dying people, could it create a potentially infinte army of smelly zombies?

Answer (score 10):

## Almost infinite Zombies in perfect circumstances

The corpse flower stat block states that the corpse flower can hold up to nine corpses. An action the corpse flower has an action called Harvest the Dead. MToF pg. 127

> *Harvest the Dead*. The corpse flower grabs one unsecured dead humanoid within 10 feet of it and stuffs the corpse inside itself, along with any equipment the corpse is wearing or carrying. The remains can be used with the Corpses trait.

Nowhere in the stat block does it say a maximum amount of zombies that can be animated.

So if the Corpse Flower has enough time and enough dead humanoid bodies it could create a vast zombie army. However, the zombies are not in the control of the Corpse Flower so there is nothing to stop them wandering off.

Comment: I think you mean arbitrarily large, not infinite.

Answer (score 7):

## It can make any number, but...

You are right that, as there is no bound given for how many zombies can be animated at once, the flower can make an arbitrarily large number of zombies, given a sufficient source of dead humanoids. There are however a few limitations:

- The flower can only store nine corpses on it, which is probably an upper band for it's rowing army as:
- The zombies are allies of the flower, but "[aren't] under its control". This means the army will have to be lead by the persuasive powers of a plant with no languages.

Comment: It may be worth noting that a zombie is smarter than a horse, and as smart as a wolf or an elephant. A zombie could easily learn to bring corpses to the flower, but I'm not sure why they would want to. Perhaps you meant to say "roving army", rather than "rowing army"?